# Why copy constructor is called instead of move constructor in my code?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I'm trying to understand a move constructor and rvalue reference.
So I tried this code on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler.
But the result confuses me.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


class A {
public:
  A() { std::cout << "Constructed" << std::endl; }
  A(const A& )= delete;
  A(A&&) { std::cout << "Move Constructed" << std::endl; }
};

int
main ()
{
  A&& a = A();
  A b = a; // error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(const A&)’
  //A b = static_cast<decltype(a)>(a); // This works, WTF?
  std::cout << std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(a)>::value << std::endl; // pretty sure a is rvalue reference.

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `decltype(id-expression)` is a weird beast with different rules to the rest of the language, here it gives you `A&&`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing with *types* and [*value categories*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

(emphasis mine)

> Each C++ expression (an operator with its operands, a literal, a variable name, etc.) is characterized by **two independent properties: a *type* and a *value category***.

As a named variable, `a` is an lvalue.

> The following expressions are *lvalue expressions*:
>
> - the name of a variable, ...
> - ...

Then for `A b = a;` the copy constructor is selected. As you've tried, `static_cast<decltype(a)>(a);` would convert it to an xvalue (which is rvalue); you can also use `std::move`.

```
A b = std::move(a);
```

> The following expressions are *xvalue expressions*:
>
> - a function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type is rvalue reference to object, such as `std::move(x)`;
> - ...

Answer (score 1):

```
A&& a = A();
```

does not give you a rvalue. One way to think any value as rvalue is that you can not get the address of it. If you can get an address of it, then it is likely an lvalue.
so, in your case

```
auto address_of_a = &a;
```

is possible (so, a is lvalue).

```
decltype(a)
```

is A&& (rvalue type). so type casting to A&& will give you rvalue

```
A b = a;
```

fails because, a is lvalue so it is looking for A(const A&).

```
A b = std::move(a); // or
A b = A{}; // rvalue
```

will succeed as now it will look for A(A&&)

```
A b;
A c = A{};
b = std::move(c);
```

will fail if you define your move assignment as deleted while

```
b = c;
```

will succeed if you define your copy assignment.

default construct/copy construct/move or copy assignment will work as long as all the element are trivially copy/movable.